# How to set current date as default value of an input?

Tags: php, date

I am doing an HTML form with an input type date(datepicker) and what I want to do is the following 'if the user sets any date,the default value is going to be that new date, if it does not happen show the first day of the current year'. How can I achieve it? Here is what I have tried.

```
 <input id="desde" name="desde" type="date" value="<?php  
 if(isset($_REQUEST['desde'])) { echo $_REQUEST['desde']; } else
if(!isset($_REQUEST['desde'])){ echo '01/'.'01/'.date('Y');}?>">
```

I have tried doing the following code shown above but if I do not put any date it does not show anything, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing the date in the wrong format - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value:

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual `value` — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date `value` is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

---

(And `if(foo) { … } else if(!foo) { … }` is unnecessary redundant, you don’t need that second `if` that checks for the exact opposite of the first one - `else` alone provides the same functionality here already.)

Answer (score 0):

first get the year and then you use it in your code. I have updated your code as below. It might help you.

```
 <input id="desde" name="desde" type="date" value="<?php  
 $year = date("Y"); 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['desde'])) { echo $_REQUEST['desde']; } else
if(!isset($_REQUEST['desde'])){ echo '01/'.'01/'.$year;}?>">
```

Comment: if(foo) { … } else if(!foo) { … } is unnecessary

Comment: unnecessary, David can remove. I have fixed the issue of getting year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> NOTE : Use yyyy-mm-dd format

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['desde']) && $_REQUEST['desde']!='') {
        $Date=$_REQUEST['desde'];
    }else{
        $Date=date('Y')."-01-01";
    }   
    ?>
```

**HTML :**

```
<input id="desde" name="desde" type="date" value="<?php echo $Date;?>">
```

**Or**

```
<input id="desde" name="desde" type="date"
               value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['desde']) && $_REQUEST['desde']!='') {
                    echo $_REQUEST['desde'];
                }else{
                    echo date('Y')."-01-01";
                }?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML date input type element always returns the date in `YEAR-MONTH-DAY` format,  If you want to set any default date then you need to provide the date in that specific format. Try this way,

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['desde'])){ echo date('Y').'-01-01';}?>">
```